# Did Odo ever transform his head into a weapon?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, episode-identification

Years and years ago, before I had ever seen *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, my friend was telling me that Odo was a badass — he described a scene where Odo transforms his head into some sort of hammer-like weapon and head-butts someone.

I thought this sounded cool, so eventually I watched all the episodes of *DS9*, but I never saw this scene or anything even close. Did I miss an episode somewhere? Was it in a deleted scene? Did Odo do anything that could have been misinterpreted as this?

Comment: In [DS9: Emissary](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2m6jo9), he turns his head into goo to allow a weapon to pass through him (14:05).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### No, Odo has never done such a thing, but Laas (another Changeling) has transformed his arm into a knife while standing beside Odo and then stabbed a Klingon. Odo has also allowed a weapon to pass through his head, and once transformed into a blob monster that attacked various people.

I've watched *DS9* completely five times over the years, and have never seen such a scene.  I've also worked my way through the bonus material and deleted scenes over the years and have never seen Odo do such a thing with his head.

That being said, in the Season 7 episode ["Chimera"](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Chimera_(episode)), Odo discovers and befriends a Changeling by the name of Laas, who fashioned a long knife from his arm and then used it to stab a Klingon, with Odo standing next to him at the time:

[image: Screenshot of Odo and Laas standing next to each other, Laas with the knife]

***This is perhaps the most violent thing that we see a Changeling do to a solid, and it is certainly the only weapon we have seen a Changeling fashion out of itself.***

You friend could have been conflating Odo and Laas, and at the same time conflating this incident with one from the pilot episode ["Emissary"](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Emissary_(episode)) (also pointed out by @Richard in a comment) where Odo had de-solidified his head to allow a weapon lobbed at him to pass through:

[image: Screenshot of Odo with a weapon passing through his head]

Finally, in the Season 2 episode ["The Alternate"](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Alternate_(episode)), Odo had inadvertently transformed into a blob monster and had attacked several people, in particular Dr. Bashir, who gets "head butted" and is knocked to the floor — although it's hard to say which part of its body the Odo monster had used. Below, Dr. Mora is also attacked by Odo in this state:

[image: Screenshot of Odo as a blob monster, Dr. Mora on the ground]

We never get a really good look at the Odo monster (the image above is the best), but this concept art gives a good idea:

[image: Drawing of Odo as a blob monster]

The Odo monster is as "badass" as it gets.

Comment: Thorough. I'm going to wait 24 hours to accept, if you don't mind. Seems very unlikely that anything else will come up. I wonder if it was this or if it was @Richard's suggestion about Odo turning his head into goo while a mace passed through it that my friend was referring to.

Comment: @Paul : It could be.  I independently thought it might have been that and was considering adding something about it to the answer.  I've added a remark about it (making note of Richard's comment too).  That's perfectly reasonable about acceptance. :-)

Comment: It is also possible that he was invoking something from the books which made use of a greater range of shapechanging due to the lack of special effects budget limitations.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : Definitely possible.  It could have been a comic, too...

Comment: It's possible, but this guy wasn't like a hardcore sci-fi fan who would have read star trek novelizations.

Comment: @Paul : In that case, I stick to the assertion that your friend is probably just mixing together several incidents.  I've added one more where Odo was shapeshifting and attacking at the same time --- "head butting" in a sense, but it's hard to say if he had a head or not during this incident!

Comment: I have a vague memory if something like this (not Odo).   Perhaps OP is confounding it with some non-Star Trek shape shifter or superhero, like Green Lantern

Comment: “The Odo monster is as "badass" as it gets” — a grim, humourless, dogged pursuit of the facts is its own form of badassery!